# In multiset , the code does not enter into compare function and throws error

Tags: c++, qt, stl, multiset

I have used breakpoints to check if my compare function is being called while inserting element into Multi-set  but it never reaches the  breakpoint.

The error `Unhandled exception at 0x003c5a71 in Regular_Calibration_d.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000014.`

I pasting the code below. Please let me know where I am doing wrong .
Couple of  important thing  in which I have a doubt .

- 1) I am manipulating  sms.message  before actually inserting it in
     multi-set   so do you guys think that I am doing something wrong
     there  which creates the probelem?
- 2) If I think for a time being
        that something is wrong with string manipulation but then why it
        doesnt hit the comapre function which compare time .

Below are my code.

structure of SMS

```
struct SMS
{
  SMS(const SMSType::Enum e, const QString& s);
  QDateTime          time;
  SMSType::Enum      smsType;
  QString            message;
};
```

//construtcor of message

```
SMS::SMS( const SMSType::Enum e, const QString& s )
: smsType( e ), message( s )
{
   time = QDateTime::currentDateTime();

}
```

//compare function

```
bool SMS_list::LessSMSTime::operator ()( const SMS& left,
                     const SMS& right ) const
{

  QDate date_left  = left.time.date();
  QDate date_right = right.time.date();

  if( date_left.year() < date_right.year() )
    return true;
  else if( date_left.year() > date_right.year() )
    return false;

  if( date_left.month() < date_right.month() )
    return true;
  else if( date_left.month() > date_right.month() )
    return false;

  if( date_left.day() < date_right.day() )
    return true;
  else if( date_left.day() > date_right.day() )
    return false;

  QTime time_left  = left.time.time(); 
  QTime time_right = right.time.time(); 

  if( time_left.hour() < time_right.hour() )
         return true;
    else if( time_left .hour() > time_right.hour() )
         return false;

 if( time_left.minute() < time_right.minute() )
         return true;
    else if( time_left.minute() > time_right.minute() )
         return false;

  if( time_left.second() < time_right.second() )
          return true;
     else if( time_left.second() > time_right.second() )
          return false;

  if( time_left.msec() < time_right.msec () )
          return true;

  return false;
}
```

//declaration of multiset

```
std::multiset<SMS, LessSMSTime> SMSSet;
```

// in some function

```
SMSSet.insert( sms ) ;
```

// string manipulation

```
void SMSInterface::output( const SMSType::Enum type, QString str_qt ) const
{

 // convert QString to std::String
 std::string str = str_qt.toStdString();
 QMutex mutex;
 mutex.lock();

 if( str[ str.length() - 1 ] == '\n' )
 {
  str = std::string( str.cbegin(),   str.cbegin() + str.length() - 1 );
 }

 //convert std::string to QString
 QString str_to_qt = QString::fromStdString ( str );
// QString str_to_qt = QString::fromUtf8 ( str.c_str() );

    SMS sms( type, str_to_qt );
    sms_list_->add_sms( message ); // inside this function multi-set insertion is called
bla bala 


 mutex.unlock();
}
```

Comment: Which line causes the assertion? (Piosting the compare function which you say it never calls is a bit strange)

Comment: Where's the string manipulation that you think is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running your program in a debugger? It will help you figure out *where* the crash happen, as well as giving you tools to try to figure out *why* it happens.

Comment: it crashes as soon as code reaches  MessageSet.insert( sms ) .

Comment: @doctorlove, which line causes assertion ?  the last line shown in my code.  Yes I did triede to run in debug mode  and  it poinst to Nodeptr& _Root() const
  { // return root of nonmutable tree
  return (this->_Parent(this->_Myhead));
  }
     in xtree.cpp file ??

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Hi Joachim , I did tried to ran my code in debugger thats how i found that problem occurs during insertion . on more debugging I found  it never touches my compare  function . While on teh otehr hand i created  small program to test multi -set   for testing purpose and found thet  code did actually hit compare function.

Comment: Is `MessageSet` null? So, it tries to insert 'sms', starts at `_Root` or ties to. And then explodes ... so it's trying to find where to insert it and doesn't get as far as your compare fn cos it blows up. Conclusion you've broken `MessageSet` somehow. And not told us anything about it.

Comment: @doctorlove, cool , I will look into it and check where have i broken it and let you guys know shortly

Comment: I'm not a guy, I'm a woman.

Comment: @doctorlove, I am so sorry..

Comment: @doctorlove, Interesting thing is when i added the code  to check if multi-set is empty or not it breaks at that point . for example just before insertion , I have done  if(SMSSet.empty() ) std::cout " bl abla" and I have noticed it broke at  if condition.

Comment: debug pointed after empty() check is  size_type size() const
  { // return length of sequence
  return (this->_Mysize);
  }
 at xtree.cpp

Comment: By NULL I mean badly initialised, rather than empty. i.e. hovver mouse over `this`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43126/discussion-between-samprat-and-doctorlove)

Comment: Your mutex, being a local variable, isn't protecting anything at all. In particular, modifications to `sms_list_` are unprotected. You need *one* mutex that is shared between all the places that access the data.

Comment: @doctorlove .. Since morning , I was barking at the wrong tree.. yes you were right I have failed to initialise the sms_list properly. Fixed the problem and now its working. Without you r help I wouldn,t able to find it out. Thanks a lot for the help. AN dthanks everyone

Comment: @molbdnilo, Thanks mate for pointing it out. I have seen some existing projects in vc++ and tehy have used crictical section as local in teh function so I thought to replicate the same here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed,

> "Access violation reading location 0x00000014"

suggested you were trying to call a member function, or read a property on something that was null.

When you posted more code, we could see

`sms_list_->add_sms( message );`

as the only thing in sight which could be `null` and in fact this hadn't been initialised and was null, hence the problem.